# Creating 6 row entries per entry created on Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbbf4.png)

In the image, I would like to create a table so that anytime I enter an item in the highlighted cells, that item appears exactly 6 times in another column. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: To avoid downvotes and get better answers in the future please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 365:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*6)/6,0))
```

[image]